# This script randomizes a MAC address--but I cannot renew DHCP afterwards

Tags: bash, network

```
#!/bin/bash
NEWMAC=`openssl rand -hex 6 | sed 's/\(..\)/\1:/g; s/.$//'`
ifconfig $1 ether $NEWMAC
ifconfig $1 down
ifconfig $1 up
```

I pass en0 or en1 as the sole argument to the script and run as sudo. When I do this, the MAC does change, however I cannot restore connectivity until I reboot and the new MAC is lost. Initially the interface displays no IP, but after a few minutes it displays an IP and claims to have DHCP information. However, I believe this is a cached data and not an actual renewal, as I cannot ping, load pages, or otherwise connect to the Internet.

I have appended this snippet with no improvement in results.

```
ipconfig set $1 BOOTP
ipconfig set $1 DHCP
```

Comment: I know it this was over three years ago, but did my solution solve your problem? If so, could you please mark it as the correct answer? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you're on MacOSX 10.5 or later, at the beginning of your script, call `sudo /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Apple80211.framework/Versions/Current/Resources/airport -z`. Another thing you could do to improve this is to call the script itself with `sudo` instead of calling `sudo` multiple times within.

Comment: When I have `sudo ifconfig $1 down` before `sudo ifconfig $1 ether $NEWMAC`, I get this error: `ifconfig: ioctl (SIOCAIFADDR): Device power is off`. I've modified the script to require sudo when calling the script.

Comment: Oh, my bad. I'll edit my answer. Did using `sudo ifconfig set $1 DHCP` work for you?

Comment: Just tested it... results in `ifconfig: interface set does not exist` and the connection remains down.

Comment: Oh, I messed up, and I edited my answer again.

Comment: Oh, I think it's `ipconfig` and not `ifconfig` for this command, sorry. I get the two mixed up. Answer updated.

Comment: I discovered that in Googling the error string. I substituted but it still isn't working. 

I'm not sure of the relationship between that command and going into System Preferences > Network > Ethernet > Advanced > Renew DHCP Lease, but I have also been renewing the lease that way, without success.

Comment: You may have to renew the BOOTP, also. I've updated my answer with the additional command.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3574/discussion-between-trav1th-and-andrew-larsson)